# Explaination of an output

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, pointers, recursion

Hi I have implemented a C code in visual C++ and and did some modification in it for debugging. Here is the code

```
long long unsigned factorial(long long unsigned int * n) {
    if (*n<=1) return 1;
    else {
        (*n)--;//This statement here .......
        printf("calculating %d * factorial %d  \n",*n,*n); -- used for debugging
        return ((*n+1) * factorial(n));
    }
}
```

The final output(value of factorial) is coming as expected but it is output of debug statement that surprises me.

```
calculating 4 * factorial 0
calculating 3 * factorial 0
calculating 2 * factorial 0
calculating 1 * factorial 0
120
```

Same value *n is used twice in every debug statement and it is showing different values. How is this possible that same value when used twice in a statement, gives different results.

Comment: Can you try printing to stderr using fprintf? Is it still doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only guessing here, but the format code `"%d"` is for `int`, while you pass a `long long`. That's a difference of 32 bits per value. Use `"%llu"` instead (`"ll"` for `long long`, the `"u"` for `unsigned`).

Comment: Its working now. But still I am curious to know why was that happening when we use %d instead of %llu. Any Logical explanation.

Comment: @MohitJain Because a `int` is 32 bits (on most platforms), and `long long` is 64 bits. The first `"%d"` reads the low 32 bits of the first `*n`, while the second `"%d"` reads the high 32 bits of that same value. The `printf` function have no idea of the actual arguments, it just knows that "now I have to print a 32-bit integer value, so get it off the stack".

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a wrong format for `unsigned long long`, test this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long unsigned factorial(long long unsigned int * n) {
    if (*n<=1) return 1;
    else {
        (*n)--;//This statement here .......
        printf("calculating %llu * factorial %llu  \n",*n,*n); 
        return ((*n+1) * factorial(n));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    long long unsigned int n = 4ULL;

    n = factorial(&n);
    printf("%llu\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the value of `n` at each recursion iteration.

When you are using recursion with a pointer:

```
return ((*n+1) * factorial(n));
```

You first calculating the value of `factorial(n)`. When the last recursion iteration is reached, you already decremented the `n` till `0`.

So, please **do not pass `n`  by reference** .

Comment: that is not a problem. When control is passed back from the function, value of variable at n is incremented by *n+1. If there would have been an error in that then final output wouldnt be correct